# FileInputStream not reading first value

Tags: java, string, file, java.util.scanner, fileinputstream

The file I need to read from looks like this:

- 30 15
- 6 3
- 12 20
- 3 4

(without the bullet points)

The inputStream isn't reading 30 and 15 but it's reading all the other ones.

How do I get the inputStream to read the first line?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Program6 {
    //  private static Fraction [] fractionArray;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the input file: ");


        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner outputFile = new Scanner(System.in);

        String inputFileName = inputFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the output file: ");
        String outputFileName = outputFile.nextLine();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFileName, true);
        //Declaring an inputstream to get file
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(inputFileName));


        //while the file still has a line
        while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            String theLine = inputStream.nextLine();
            if (theLine.length() >= 0) {
                //declares a numerator and denominator from the file
                int num = inputStream.nextInt();
                int denom = inputStream.nextInt();
                //new fraction from file
                Fraction fract = new Fraction(num, denom);
                fract.reduce();
                System.out.println(fract);
                fileWriter.write("" + fract + "\r\n");
            }
        }

        //closes streams and flushes the file writer
        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is `Scanner.nextLine()` consumes the line of input from the InputStream.  Then, using `Scanner.nextInt()` goes back to consume from that same InputStream - it does not consume from the value returned by `nextLine()`.

So, use one or the other.

If using the `nextLine()` approach, then the String containing the line will need to be parsed to extract the values.  Using `scanner.nextInt()`, the integer value from the file is immediately available.  The only loss is that then you lose knowledge of whether values were on the same line or different lines.

Comment: Not really.  I'll add a little detail.

Comment: I did this:  String theLine = inputStream.nextLine();                            int num =  Integer.parseInt(theLine);
int denom =   Integer.parseInt(theLine);    and I get a NumberFormatException

Comment: Yes, because each call to parseInt() uses the entire line - they are not consuming from a stream of input.  Try to consider how the code you are using works from an objective point-of-view, and then how it will work for you.